# what '-DLOCAL' flag does in C++ compilation

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, local, compiler-flags

I want to know what `-DLOCAL` flag of C++ compilation does ?
which is used as :

```sh
g++ -std=c++17 -Wshadow -Wall -o "%e" "%f" -g -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -DLOCAL
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one use that I found is compiled with `-DLOCAL` flag allows us to run a statement like `cerr`, which is for testing

`cerr << "some variable for testing";`

if we remove `-DLOCAL` flag in the compilation, `cerr` will not be showing any output on the console.

this is helpful even we forget to remove all those testing statements it will not affect the program. because we are not compiling with `-DLOCAL` in general.
thanks

Comment: This might be true in your specific code, but it's not true in general. Presumably you have an `#ifdef LOCAL` somewhere, but nobody apart from yourself had any way to know this.

Answer (score 4):

The `-D` command line argument Defines a pre-processor macro. `-DLOCAL` defines macro `LOCAL` with value 1. This macro has no special meaning in the C++ language, and no special meaning for the GCC compiler.